# does dispatcher servlet check if beans are already initialized by contextLoaderlistener?

Tags: spring

I added -servlet XML in context param. This servlet file got loaded twice once by contextLoaderListener and again by dispatcher servlet.

When I checked with visualvm I got 2 instance for each class mentioned in -servlet XML. 
Doesn't spring check for existence of bean ? 
Doesn't the Ids of beans collide ?
When getwebapplicationcontext.getbean method is used which instance of bean is returned ?
Please help

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath*:dispatcher-servlet-servlet</param-value>
</context-param>


<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: could you show your configuration?

Comment: @SergiAlmar I have added the xml.